# Try to install my own extension via composer in TYPO3

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

My first steps with `TYPO3 CMS`and `composer`... but I cannot install my own distribution package. Try to:

```
composer require stsa/hellotypo3
```

I've got this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                           
 Could not find a version of package stsa/hellotypo3 matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.
```

I've install `TYPO3 9.5.1` via composer and (for testing) install a 3rd party extension like `mask` with `composer require mask/mask`. It works perfectly.

Here's my `composer.json` of my distribution extension, which I've uploaded to `packgist`. The json-file is valid, but there must be sth. wrong ..

```
{
    "name": "stsa/hellotypo3",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "FLUID Templates & TypoScript",
    "homepage": "https://www.hello.de/",
    "keywords": [
        "TYPO3",
        "CMS",
        "extension"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Stsa",
            "email": "contact@hello.de",
            "role": "Developer",
            "homepage": "https://www.hello.de/"
        }
    ],
    "license": [
        "GPL-2.0-or-later"
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^9.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Stsa\\Hellotypo3\\": "Classes/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "hellotypo3": "self.version",
        "typo3-ter/hellotypo3": "self.version"
    }
}
```

No way .. it doesn't work with that. I also try to set `"minimum-stability": "stable"`. But honestly, I have no idea what I can do ..?! Can someone help me? Thanks.

EDIT 1: Today I've update my own extension at packgist. It must be available now with this vendor/name.

EDIT 2: Now I've made a test extension via [sitepackagebuilder](https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com), upload to git, sumbit to packgist. Try to install via `composer require hellotypo3de/hellotest` .. still the same Error warning: `Could not find a version of package hellotypo3de/hellotest matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.` ..?! Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to install your local distribution extension manually. You have to insert your extension at the "require-section" and add a new type of package at the "repositories-section" in your repsoitory root `composer.json`. See my example:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
              "name": "stsa/hellotypo3",
              "version":"master",
              "source": {
                  "url": "https://github.com/name/hellotypo3-distribution.git",
                  "type": "git",
                  "reference":"dev-master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^5.5.5",
        "typo3/minimal": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^9.5",
        "stsa/hellotypo3": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
            "web-dir": "public"
        }
    }
}
```

`dev-master` is here important!

The `composer.json`from your extension looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "stsa/hellotypo3",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "FLUID Templates & TypoScript",
    "homepage": "https://www.hellotypo3.de/",
    "keywords": [
        "TYPO3",
        "CMS",
        "extension"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "StSa",
            "email": "hello@hellotypo3.de",
            "role": "Developer",
            "homepage": "https://www.hellotypo3.de/"
        }
    ],
    "license": [
        "GPL-2.0-or-later"
    ],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^9.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Stsa\\Hellotypo3\\": "Classes/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "hellotypo3": "self.version",
        "typo3-ter/hellotypo3": "self.version"
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "extension-key": "hellotypo3"
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can install your extension from packgist, but don't forget:

```
composer require stsa/hellotypo3:master-dev@dev
```

or

```
composer req stsa/hellotypo3:@dev
```

Answer (score 8):

I assume you want to use your extension only on one installation as local extension. So that's the way to go:

1. Create a directory, e.g. `packages` in your project's root directory.
2. Move your extension into this directory and name the folder `stsa-hellotypo3`. The part before the dash is your namespace, the part behind the package name.
3. Add to your `composer.json` of your extension the following entry:

   ```
   "extra": {
       "typo3/cms": {
           "extension-key": "stsa_hellotypo3"
       }
   }
   ```

   Now TYPO3 will use `stsa_hellotypo3` as extension key.
4. Change into your `composer.json` file in your TYPO3 project root the `repositories` entry:

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "path",
           "url": "packages/*"
       },
       {
           "type": "composer",
           "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
       }
   ],
   ```

   composer will look now into the `packages` folder for packages to install.
5. Now you can add your extension to the project:

   ```
   composer require stsa/hellotypo3:@dev
   ```

   The extension is symlink'ed as stsa_hellotypo3 in typo3conf/ext/ directory. With the `@dev` the development version is installed (which you have). you can also add a version entry into your extension's `composer.json` file, then you can omit the `@dev`.

If you do it that way you don't have to add your extension's autoloading information to the root composer.json file.

Comment: Hi Chris, today I_ve upload my distribution to packgist. `https://packagist.org/packages/stsa/hellotypo3?query=hellotypo3. I try it later, and also with your tutorial, thanks for the moment. But, ist my composer.json correct? Or why is there always a problem with the minimm stability?

Comment: Hi Chris, the local installation is not working: `Could not find a matching version of package stsa/hellotypo3@dev. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).` Now I have also update my distribution extension at packgist and try it also via `composer require stsa/hellotypo3`, but this also fails ..? I'm still looking for help to install my own extension from packgist or github.

Comment: If you don't have a version in your local composer.json it is assumed as dev version. If you don't have a tag in your repository (which is then the version for packagist) it is also assumed as dev. SO if you look at your packagist package you'll see the only version is dev-master. You can use for version "@dev" or "master-dev@dev" to signal that you want the dev version withour setting the minimum-stability property globally. Use `composer req stsa/hellotypo3:@dev`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you Chris. This info should be placed at https://composer.typo3.org/

Comment: `composer validate`gives an error: `- require.jambagecom/party : unbound version constraints (@dev) should be avoided`. So the `@dev` seems to be unwanted from composer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
"require": {
        "typo3/cms-core:^9.5"
    },
```

Does that work? If not sry, but hope it helps

Comment: Hi Rustyjim, thanks for your help. No, your answer does not help. After this the `composer.json`isn't valid anymore. I'm looking the composer file in other extensions and it looks like mine?!