# I cant find my PHP class in a TYPO3 extension with my template. Errorcode 1407060572

Tags: php, templates, typo3

I wrote an extension for a TYPO3 site (Version 10.4.15) and in there you have to access the database with a ViewHelper class. The path of the ViewHelper class is

**websitename/public/typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Classes/ViewHelpers/GetRecordViewHelper.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace mwatschong\sitepackage\ViewHelpers;


    use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
    use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
    use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

    use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
    use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

    class GetRecordViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
    {
      use CompileWithRenderStatic;

      public function initializeArguments()
      {
        $this->registerArgument('land', 'string','the land which is rendered', true);
      }
      public static function renderStatic(
         array $arguments,
         \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
         RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
      ) }
      $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_patentsites_content');
      $resultSet = $connection->query('SELECT text FROM tx_patentsites_content WHERE land = $arguments['land']')->execute();
    return $resultSet
      }
    }
```

I integrate my class into my Template by

```
{namespace patent=mwatschong\sitepackage\ViewHelpers}
```

and invoke my ViewHelper as

`<patent:getRecord land="Albanien" />`

But I get the Errorcode 1407060572 which means the fluidparser can't find my class.

I hope it is enough information for discussing the problem.

EDIT:

I add to my composer.json a autoload clause, changed nothing, but is per default in the composer.json of the example plugins from the typo3 docs, StoreInventory and the SJROffer Example.

```
        "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "mwatschong\\sitepackage\\": "Classes/"
    }
```

EDIT:

I first try first to "load classes with composermode" from
[the typo3doku](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html#loading-classes-with-composer-mode) and no reference to my package classes are filed in the autoload_psr4.php. I try to add them manually to this file (`'mwatschong\\sitepackage\\' => array($baseDir . '/public/typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Classes')`) but sadly no diffrences.

EDIT:

I do the whole Thing from Scratch with the [sitepackagebuilder](https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/) and still have no luck. I have the check the Spelling based on the blog as suggested in the answers. Here is the new composer.json

```
{
    "name": "mvision/patentsites",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "description": "Create Patentsites from Database",
    "license": ["GPL-2.0-or-later"],
    "keywords": ["TYPO3 CMS"],
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^10.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mvision\\Patentsites\\": "Classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

I do `composer dumpautoload`  and check my autoload_psr4. There is no Reference to my package.

EDIT

I run `composer req mvision/patentsites -vvv`  and it outputs that the minimum stability is not matched. But in my ext_emconf.php is the state set to stable and the extensionmanager showed it also.

EDIT

I work through this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461434/15940722) in a other typo3/ composer thread an know i can load my classes without problems. I think the Problem was a false composer/repo configuration.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: 1) did you include the static TS of your extension to your main TS? 2) did you clear all caches in the backend?

Comment: @biesior Thanks for your Answer! I Try to clear the cache already, it doesn't work, but what do you mean with the 'TS', i'am not sure if you mean the TSconfig or the main Template or something else.

Comment: Go to your main TypoScript template (backend,left pane, `WEB > Template > Info/modify > Edit whole...`  there go to `Includes` tab, make sure that in `Include static (from extensions)` selector your ext is included on the left side of the selector.

Comment: Ah thanks. Yes my extension is under the selected items.

Comment: also did you dump autoloaded classes from BE? `Admin tools > Maintenance > Rebuild PHP Autoload Information` ?

Comment: @biesior This option is greyed out with the explanation: "You can't use this feature, because your installation is in composer mode. Guide: Composer dumpautoload." But I added a autoload information to my extension. (see the first edit)

Comment: I'd use composer's autoload dump and allow to recreate it by TYPO3 itself : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html. That way you have sure you didn't make a typo.

Comment: Are you sure, autoloading is working with lowercase vendor and package namespaces?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Now I tried to change that and have now a Extension with uppercase letter vendor, and package namespace (I created it with the [Sitepackagebuilder](https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/success/)) still no loading

Comment: Just to be sure: you have *activated* your extension, too?

Comment: Yes, with Admintools > Extensions. I have also tried the Store-Inventory example package an it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Blogpost "[composer.json specification for TYPO3 extensions](https://insight.helhum.io/post/148886148725/composerjson-specification-for-typo3-extensions)" by Helmut Hummel, telling

> The PHP namespace prefix for psr-4 MUST only have two parts, where the first MUST be your vendor name in upper camel case and the second MUST be your extension name in upper camel case.

Comment: I tryed it from scratch with the sitepackagebuilder from typo3 as described in my latest edit. still no luck